# Rails custom logger logs same request multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, activesupport

I am using a custom logger in my engine's initializers folder. Code looks like this:

```
@@duration_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/duration_logger.log")

ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "game.players" do |name, start, finish, id, data|
  @@duration_logger.info("Request: #{data}")
end
```

When i do the request, first logging is fine, but the second request is logged 2 times, third request is logged 3-4 times. And following requests are logged multiple times. What is going on? Am i doing something wrong?

I am calling to the subscriber from my controller action

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("game.players", :data => @result)
```

Comment: put a `puts "here"` inside the `subscribe` block - it smells like you subscribe over and over again...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was the rails bug in 4.0. It recreates the Subscriber object every time a request comes.

Here is the issue I created:

[Github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15193)

Here is the pull request that is merged

[Pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15037)

Updating to the latest version fixed the problem.